# How to run multiple instances of a Django app?

Tags: django, python-3.x

This question doesn't involve any code. I just want to know a way to run multiple instances of a django app and if it is really possible in the first place.

I make django apps and host them on Apache. With the apps, I noticed a conflict between multiple users accessing the web app.

Let us assume it is a web scraping app. If one user visits the app and run the scraper, the other user accessing the site from a different location doesn't seem to be able to visit the app or run the scraper unless the scraping that the first user started finishes.

Is it really possibe to make it independent for all different users accessing the app?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could approach this. You might consider putting your app into a container (Google search: docker {your stack})

Then implement something like Docker Swarm or Kubernetes to allocate multiple instances of your app.

That being said, you might consider how to refactor your app to allow multiple users. It sounds like your scraping process locks things. But in reality, there's no reason your server should lock up during this.

It might be better to create your app so that when it received a request, like someone visiting the site, the server pays out the requested web page. When a user asks for a scrape/task to run, the server calls your scaper service or script asynchronously.

That way your app can still function while a scrape is in progress. This would be MUCH more resource efficient (and likely simpler) than spinning up tens or hundreds of instances of your entire app.

tl;Dr: containerization for multiple instances 
Refactor app so a single user can't threadlock it.

Comment: Yes that makes sense and I have even tried that. Actually, when a user runs a scrape, I want to keep him updated with the progress of scrape. I don't want this progress to be visible when another user visits the app. Can you please help how this can be achieved? Thanks

Comment: @UmarAftab It'll depend so much on how it was built. Recommend looking up resources on "asynchronous web apps" and tutorial videos on YouTube. Then you'll be able to apply it. A quick search rendered me this resource : "https://buildwithdjango.com/blog/post/celery-progress-bars/"

Comment: @UmarAftab generally speaking, you'll want your web server to process requests, but not perform the requests. So if a user visits the site, give the user a webpage. If the user requests a scrape, create an async request for the scrape to occur that the server doesn't need to wait for. All the server does is play quarterback for incoming requests and passes it to the correct place. Good luck

Comment: does it make sense to include user authentication to make the app handle each user independently? Thanks

Comment: Short answer: Yes, you'll want to tie each request to a user. However, it is going to depend a bit on what your goal with the app is. If you want users to have accounts where they can see previous scrapes, re-do scrapes, login and logout while a scrape is ongoing, then yes that would be necessary. 

But if the app isn't meant for user accounts and scrapes are meant to happen right now. Then you could get away without authentication

Comment: As of current scenario, when a user starts a scrape, a global variable is initialized that is further used to track the status of the scrape. When another user runs a scrape in another browser window, that global variable is again initialized that conflicts with the previous scrape. Is there a way using which I can tie each request to its own variable to keep the track of it? Thanks

Comment: There are many ways to do this, unfortunately, I can't tell you the "best" way for your scenario. Generally, setting Global Variables is not an ideal practice. You'll likely have to refactor your code. 

If this is meant to be webapp, take a look at "traversy media" videos on youtube on webapp building. That'll be a great place to get  you started.